# Python can't read long string number from Excel correctly

Tags: python, excel, string, numbers, long-integer

When I read Excel long number data by Python in linux,
it can't get correct value: .e.g.

666896190981400000

77798171000076400000

it will get value as following:

666896190981400064

77798171000076402688

I try add a formula to convert it as string "=Trim(A1)"
and read formula cell still get wrong value.
Anybody has good idea for it?
My source code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pycel.excelcompiler import ExcelCompiler

wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb.active
print("A1:", ws['A1'].value)
col = ws['A']

i = 0
for cell in col:
    i= i+1
    ws['A' + str(i)].number_format = '0'
    ws['B' + str(i)].value = "=\"ID\" & A" + str(i)
    ws['C' + str(i)].value = "=Trim(A" + str(i) + ")"
wb.save('test1.xlsx')
wb.close()

excel = ExcelCompiler('test1.xlsx')
value = excel.evaluate('SHEET1!B1")
print("Value-B1:", value)
value = excel.evaluate('SHEET1!C2')
print("Value-B2:", value)
```

Comment: Python does it just fine.  Excel can't handle integers that big, so it converts them to floats.  A float only has about 15 digits of precision.  What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: In fact I need read an ID key, it's OK for 15 digits of precision, but it changed last number so I can't match with other Key. As it in Linux server I can't process it by call Excel app convert to string. Many thanks for your review and anyway I can get correct string?

Comment: Why do you need to use `ExcelCompiler` here?